# Get XML data from attachment and added it to the record

Tags: xml-parsing, contacts, odoo-14

The XML data was being attached from the email. How can I reflect the XML data to the records after it was received from email to odoo?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those attachments are stored in the ir.attachments table and is linked to the document via the res_model and res_id fields. For example:

```
import base64

attachments = self.env['ir.attachment'].search([('res_model', '=', 'your.model'), ('res_id', '=', record_id)])
for a in attachments:
    print(base64.b64decode(a.datas))
```